# Error when scraping 2019 data with nflscrapR. Just started getting it

Tags: r

Everything was working great up to last Tuesday. Ran it again this weekend and today, getting the error:

**Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) :
embedded nul in string: '\037‹\b'**

> install.packages("devtools")
>
> devtools::install_github(repo = "maksimhorowitz/nflscrapR")
>
> library(nflscrapR)
>
> pbp_2019 <- scrape_season_play_by_play(2019, weeks = 9)

I expected to get the data as always, but this error above always pops up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like there is already a [related issue in the github issues](https://github.com/maksimhorowitz/nflscrapR/issues/133). My guess is that the website changes how they are serving up data. Web scraping is very delicate and can break easily when a website gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just redownloaded nflscrapR. I had to add 'force = TRUE' to the 'install_github()' command to get it to actually redownload.